# Refreshing SharedPreference to retrieve fresh data when user loggedin

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have been successful in writing a code to retrieve and store user data using sharedpreference. However as long as the user is loggedin any changes made to the data does not show unless user logout.

Here is my code:

```
public class SharedPrefManager {
private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "my_shared_preff";
private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
private Context mCtx;
private SharedPrefManager(Context mCtx) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
}
public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context mCtx) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(mCtx);
    }
    return mInstance;
}
public void saveUser(User user) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("id", user.getId());
    editor.putString("email", user.getEmail());
    editor.putString("firstname", user.getFirstName());
    editor.putString("lastname", user.getLastName());
    editor.putString("companyname", user.getCompanyName());
    editor.putString("address1", user.getAddress1());
    editor.putString("city", user.getCity());
    editor.putString("state", user.getState());
    editor.putString("postcode", user.getPostcode());
    editor.putString("country", user.getCountry());
    editor.putString("phonenumber", user.getPhonenumber());
    editor.putString("status", user.getStatus());
    editor.putInt("currency", user.getCurrency());
    editor.putString("credit", user.getCredit());
    editor.putString("language", user.getLanguage());
    editor.putInt("email_verified", user.getEmail_verified());
    editor.apply();
}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getInt("id", -1) != -1;
}
public User getUser() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return new User(
            sharedPreferences.getInt("id", -1),
            sharedPreferences.getString("email", null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("firstname", null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("lastname", null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("companyname", null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("address1", null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("city", null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("state", null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("postcode", null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("country", null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("phonenumber", null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("status", null),
            sharedPreferences.getInt("currency", -1),
            sharedPreferences.getString("credit", null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("language", null),
            sharedPreferences.getInt("email_verified", 1)
    );
}

public Emails getEmails() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return new Emails(
            sharedPreferences.getString("subject", null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("message", null)

    );
}

public void clear() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
}

}
```

Is there a way to add a background refresh activity to SharedPreference whereby code retrieves and update stored data without logging the user out?

Comment: you really do not want to use shared pref in this manner. you firebase, or parseserver, or even php. you can then use shared pref (IF and ONLY if) you NEED to. I use firebase and php (firebase for users and php for saving data) and i only use shared pref to save instances. for example, i have a 'first time user' activity. i wont show it if they already viewed it. THAT is the MAIN purpose of shared pref. what you are doing is not something shared pref should be used for.

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` already does this. Instead of reading out everything from the `SharedPreferences` in `getUser` and `getEmails`, you should read an individual preference when you need its value. Whenever you read a value from the `SharedPreferences` object, you'll get its latest value every time.

One way you might do this is by getting rid of your `SharedPrefManager` class, give your `User` class a `SharedPreferences` member, and implement `User.getId` to call `sharedPrefs.getInt("id")` and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am a beginner and still learning alot. Can you give more details on how to go about this so sharedPrefs is able to get latest values from the database

Answer (score 0):

You can register a listener using sharedprefs. registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.

Also you are writing a lot of boilerplate code to read/write on shared preferences. You can use something like [this](https://github.com/amin-amini/EasyPrefs).